Bake exact world position values to image texture using UV map
Given a mesh with a UV map, I want to bake the exact world position to an image texture. Just like a normal bake, where the RGB value of each pixel in the image texture represents the x/y/z coordinate of the surface normal, but now with the x/y/z world coordinates.
Just to be clear, for the standard cube, the normal bake would look like this:

That's what I want, but for the world position instead.
It is important to me that the position values do not get rescaled or distorted in any way because I need to use them for a downstream scientific application (the mesh represents some object in a volumetric dataset, and rescaling/distortion will mess up the correspondence between the mesh and the volumetric data).
I would like to do this via a script, if possible. Ideally I would be able to access the result as a numpy array in Blender's scripting window.
I have so far tried two things: baking in Cycles with Bake Type "Position" often just results in a black image. Setting up a material with nodes Geometry(Position) -> (Color)Emission(Emission) -> (Surface)Material Output and baking in Cycles with Bake Type "Emit" results in a distorted image. The position values get rescaled in a way that I don't understand and also non-linearly distorted.
I could implement my own position bake "manually" by coding up something, but I think there must be a solution using Blender's own tools?
Thanks!

The second process is probably the correct one, can you show the results for analysis?

For the color values being wrong part, it's probably due to color management. In render properties ->color management, set the view transform to standard.
